# Badges, badges, badges...?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

(Mushroom mushroom.)

The iOS app shows how many badges of each color someone has, but there doesn't seem to be a way to list anyone's badges — it's not in the profile views.

It's handy when responding to questions to get an idea of a poster's background that's more detailed than just reputation (but more of a summary than just looking through their whole post history).

Comment: Why would knowing a poster's background help with answering his question?

Comment: Know your audience. For example, does a poster have tag badges in the subject at hand (or related subjects)? Or is their background in different subjects? Good teaching is tailored to the student, even if it tries to also address a general audience.

Comment: it's a snake... oh snake... it's a snake... err, ahem, Android app also doesn't have this. I'd say, this is an okay feature-request, but the priority is not too high (more or less a cosmetic feature, with exceptional case like yours)

Comment: @Mhmd If you understand who you're talking to, it helps communication with them. When attempting moderation, it's also extraordinarily helpful to know what someone's done on a site, so education abut user background is good then too.